# Is there a word for burying one's head in the sand?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

As in a concise way to describe someone who routinely either denies he has a problem in the first place, or if he does accept that problem as existent, he puts it out of his mind as soon as possible and will even go so far as to resort to alcohol, drug use or promiscuity to distract himself from the problem rather than confront it.

Like a combination of "*avoidant*" and "*person who undermines his own reality*." "*Person who banishes all his problems to an elephant graveyard where they fester and wait to resurge.*"

"***Self-distractive***" is what I came up with, but I feel like that's not a word. Plus, I want a more malicious connotation - "distraction" makes it sound too harmless and quirky.

Comment: An **ostrich**.

Comment: Anecdotally, we say "struisvogelen" in Dutch (which means "to ostrich").

Comment: Such a person would often be described as ***in denial***.

Comment: @jxh: um, ostriches don't bury their heads in the sand. You might as well have proposed "whale" for all the sense it makes.

Comment: While ostriches don't actually bury their heads, it is an English idiom.

Comment: @Patroclus: why exactly does it have to be a single word? (FumbleFingers' suggestion is the best, but even that one's technically two words.) What part of speech exactly are you after? (There is no such thing as a combination of "avoidant" and "person who X". It has to be either the one or the other.) What kind of context and register are we talking about? What does your sentence look like? You do have all that information, but still can't find a good fit. We don't have all that information, so if anything we can only do worse not better.

Comment: @AndrewLeach it is an idiom in every language I am aware of. Doesn't mean that if I said "Putin is an ostrich" you would have the slightest idea what the hell I am on about.

Comment: Context is all. If you said "On North Korea, Putin is behaving like an ostrich," then it's immediately clear that he's ignoring the problem.

Comment: Precisely. Which is just a different way of saying, you can't use a single word, you have to use many.

Comment: Reg, as Andrew says, it is well enough known that you can say "Putin is Ostriching" and be understood. It's not great, grammatically, but it works.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I was aware the word I offered had weaknesses, which is why it is not an answer. However, there are very few words that do not take on different meanings when used in different contexts.

Comment: @RegDwigHt Remember young Simba from The Lion King when he goes off to the Hakuna Matata place? He's avoidant, yes, but that has a connotation of anxiety and fear to it. Even though there is anxiety and fear in this context, it's a very blissfully ignorant type of very low-lying anxiety that allows for a lot of joviality in the meanwhile? I'm looking for either an adjective or noun that gets that across - "having a jovial, almost celebratory attitude while danger lurks."

Answer (score 1):

'Avoiding the issue' cries for words like eschewal. But you specifically mention the need to have a 'in denial' connotation.

I suggest the word: **Ostrichism**:
*The deliberate avoidance or ignorance of conditions as they exist : self-delusion* {http://useful_english.enacademic.com/255289/ostrichism}